# setPrice() not working

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, programmatically

I want to change the price of a particular product via a module but it is not working. I have searched and found a lot of solutions but none is working for me. I'm relatively new to Magento, I'm missing something but don't know what.. The stock is changing but the price isn't.

This is my code:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$sku = 170994;
$stock = 20;
$price = 17.95;

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
if ($product) {
    $productId = $product->getId();
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);              
    $stockItem->setData('qty', $stock);
    if($stock <= 0){
        $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 0);              
    } else {
        $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
    }
    $stockItem->setPrice($price);
    echo $stockItem->getPrice() . '<br>';
    $stockItem->save();  
/*
    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(2);
    $process->reindexAll();
*/
    unset($stockItem);
    unset($product);
    echo 'done';
} else {
    echo 'no product found';
}
```

And I have added this code as well but then nothing happens:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STOR‌​E_ID);
```

Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but it should work if you set price on product object, instead of stockitem.

Please try

```
$product->setPrice($price);
$product->save();
```

**Update:**

It works this way, but you have to set

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

You have written, that you tried that, but it seems there is a hidden char in your constant name. See image ...

[image]

or check here: https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php

Comment: Nope, this is not working

Comment: @fomfur updated and tested :)